# MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111

Tags: php, sql

I moved my site to **godaddy server**, but the SQL connection is not working even with adequate changes which was working perfectly fine before

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('www.xxxxx.com', 'phpadminusername', 'phpadminpasswor');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
/*echo 'Connected successfully';*/
echo "DB CONNECTION :<font color='green'>ACTIVE</font>";


?>
```

It is showing an error

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to
>   MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error:
>   111 in /home/content/58/9508458/html/psychiatric/private.php on line
>   196 Could not connect: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading
>   initial communication packet', system error: 111

Answer (score 6):

fixed by updating to hostname in account manager specifically given by godaddy.com .. not just the domain name

Comment: You can locate the custom host for each database in your Go Daddy account.
1. Log in to your Account Manager.
2. Click Web Hosting.
3. Next to the hosting account you want to use, click Launch.
4. In the Databases section of the Hosting Control Center, click the MySQL icon.
5. Click the pencil icon next to the database you would like to get connection strings for to open its edit features.
6. Click the Configuration icon in the menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

That probably means mySQL is configured to only listed to requests from a particular hosts (or hosts). You can tell MySQL to only accept packets from particular IP addresses (usually localhost, but it may be wider on GoDaddy - not sure as I don't use them).

Check your connection string - specifically the 'www.xxxxx.com' bit. This might need to be 'localhost' or a specific IP address.