# Connection failed

Tags: mysql, connection

i am connecting data base in php page with correct username & password but a access denied problem is occoured. i checked many times my username n password are correct than why this error is occoured. help me the error or warning is given bellow
 "Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 in /home/dewasdia/public_html/main.php on line 7
fail"

i am using this function

```
    function connection()
     {
    mysql_connect('xyz.com','username','password') or die (" fail");
    mysql_select_db('dewasdia_dewas') or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Comment: Check your Mysql connection binding, that is if your mysql is accessible from localhost only or <public_ip> or <public_domain> .
Example - 
if your mysql allows only localhost to get connection, then you won't be able to access it through xyz.com

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168945/mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communication-packet-system-error-111)

Refer to that question. It is the exact question required for you.