# Lost mysql connection after form submit

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, vtiger

I am using **[vtiger CRM](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Developer_Guide)**. The CRM contains a module 'Products', and the module provides to take duplicate of products. If we create a duplicate product , it lost MySQL connection. It shows an error

```
"Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111"
```

Also I can't login to MySQL database.It shows `'Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.'`
My code is

```
    $dbconfig['db_server'] = '127.0.0.1';
    $dbconfig['db_port'] = ':3306';
    $dbconfig['db_hostname'] = $dbconfig['db_server'].$dbconfig['db_port'];
```

I am also using 'localhost' instead of '127.0.0.1'.
First time it works perfectly , but after submitting the form the connection is lost. Any one please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Usually it indicates network connectivity trouble and you should check the condition of your network if this error occurs frequently. If the error message includes “during query,” this is probably the case you are experiencing.
Sometimes the “during query” form happens when millions of rows are being sent as part of one or more queries. If you know that this is happening, you should try increasing net_read_timeout from its default of 30 seconds to 60 seconds or longer, sufficient for the data transfer to complete.*

read here:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-lost-connection.html

or check your server configuration once if the same problem exists.

check the following post also.[MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168945/mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communication-packet-system-error-111)